# Best solution for transpiling Typescript into ES6 without transpiling of Async?

Tags: typescript, async-await, npm-scripts

sorry the title perhaps makes you confused, let me explain of it:

our JS environment is a little bit special, fully ES6 support without native generator `function*` and `yield`, so the Typescript code:

```
async test(): Promise {
    return await Promise.resolve();
}
```

will be Transpiled into ES6:

```
function test() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () { return yield Promise.resolve(); });
}
```

but, wryly... our env does not support native generator..
and, also we can't transpile TS into ES5, because there a few of libs referenced by the proj are ES6 modules, so if you transpile TS into ES5, the class can't be inherited (ES5 uses __extends to do this)

so I'm finding a solution to transpile our TS codes into ES6 but with all `async` in it transpiled into ES5 like style (`tslib.js`)

I can accept whatever solutions, npm / node / post scripts / TS features whatever, what I need is clues! thanks guys.

Comment: Haven't personally tried this, but in theory you could use TS to get to ES6, then run [babel](https://babeljs.io) on the output with *only* the plugins for async/await and generators.

Comment: hi @ecraig12345, thanks, yes I have tried this, but the babel plugin always throws 'ForOfStatement' error, I have no idea what's wrong because for...of is a standard syntax of ES6.. so I changed to another way, but still failed, so I had to post this on stackoverflow.

Comment: If the main thing you care about is preserving classes, maybe you could use an additional babel plugin to get rid of for/of loops?

Comment: this is the least requirement, classess should work first, so you mean use some ForOf plugins to tranpile `for...of` and `async` syntax together at the same time to avoid the errors?

Comment: Yes, like [this one](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-for-of). I'm not very familiar with Babel setup but I assume there's a way to specify an ordered list of plugins to run.

Comment: this works! thanks so much @ecraig12345, I'll share my result as there are still no answers to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ecraig12345 for the tips.

Actually to achieve this, you have to use `Babel` plugin to transpile the JS generated from TS source again.

The steps:

1, normally compile and output JS files from your TS project.

2, use `npm` to install Babel and related plugins:

> `@babel/cli`
>
> `@babel/core`
>
> `@babel/runtime`
>
> `@babel/plugin-transform-for-of`
>
> `@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator`
>
> `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`

3, edit your `.babelrc` file and use this content:

    `{
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of",
            "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator",
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
        ]
    }`

4, edit your `tasks.json` of your TS project:

    `{
    ....
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "deployTs",
                "group": "build",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "tsc TS_OUTPUT_JS_FOLDER/ --module commonjs --target es6"
            },
            {
                "label": "deployFinal",
                "group": "build",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "npx babel TS_OUTPUT_JS_FOLDER/ -d RE_TRANSPILE_OUTPUT_FOLDER/",
                "dependsOn": ["depolyTs"],
                "dependsOrder": "sequence"
            },
            ....
        ]
    ....
    }`

5, and then just execute `deployFinal` task by menu Terminal > Run Tasks, and the task will first compile TS and then run Babel to transpile `async` syntax in the output folder step by step.

Have fun.